# Woocommerce add min quantity and step to product page by using product_tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to implement a code that adds a minimum necessary quantity if a product_tag is used for the product.

I found this code:

```
    // Set minimum quantity per product before checking out
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'rohil_set_min_total' );
    function rohil_set_min_total() {
        // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
        if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {

            global $woocommerce, $product;
            $i=0;
            //$prod_id_array = array();
            //loop through all cart products
            foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) :


                // Set minimum product cart total
                $minimum_cart_product_total = 12;

                // See if any product is from the bagel category or not
                if ( has_term( 'bagels', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) ) :

                    $total_quantity += $product['quantity'];
                    //array_push($prod_id_array, $product['product_id']);
                endif;

            endforeach;

            foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) :
                if ( has_term( 'bagels', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) ) :
                    if( $total_quantity < $minimum_cart_product_total && $i == 0 ) {
                        // Display our error message
                        wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s products is required from bagel category before checking out.</strong>'
                            . '<br />Current number of items in the cart: %s.',
                            $minimum_cart_product_total,
                            $total_quantity ),
                        'error' );
                    }
                    $i++;
                endif;
            endforeach;
        }

    }
```

I tried to modify product_cat to product_tag but something didnt work.

And the other problem is that i want to set my minimum order directly on the product page (for example you can only add 12 or increments of 12 in the cart). Not to notify you when you check out, but directly to make the user to buy the minimum input.

I hope you understand and can help a girl out :)

Thank you.